# Remove lines with more than x digits

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, word-list

I'd like to find a way to delete lines containing more than 4 digits using awk or sed:

input:

```
test12test1
test154test43test
test12
```

desired output:

```
test12test1
test12
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9]` matches a line with at least 5 digits.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it's working

Answer (score 5):

One of these may do.

```
awk -F '[0-9]' 'NF<=5' file
test12test1
test12

awk -F '[0-9]' 'NF<6' file
test12test1
test12
```

Set the field separator to any possible decimal digit and then perform a test on the total number of fields.
Since you get a field before and after the field-separator, you need to test if the line more than 5 fields to determine if the line has more than 4 decimals.

Answer (score 3):

The perl `tr///` operator returns the *number* of substitutions, so

```
perl -ne 'print if tr/0-9/0-9/ <= 4' file
```

Or if you want to use a shell variable

```
max_digits=4
perl -sne 'print unless tr/0-9/0-9/ > $max' -- -max=$max_digits file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[0-9]/&/4;T;d' file
```

If one can replace the 4th digit, then delete the line.